# Forcing the comma to be the decimal separator in a script meant to run on any localization of the Oracle database

Tags: oracle

I want to set a format mask for numeric conversions in order to get "ALWAYS" the comma as decimal separator no matter what is set in the session. In other words I aim to force this format mask to always win on any localization of the Oracle database.

My session has set

```
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=',.'
```

When i issue theese commands, I get:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( 100.34,'fm099999999999999D00') FROM DUAL;
000000000000100,34 -- as desired

SELECT TO_CHAR( 100.34,'fm099999999999999.00') FROM DUAL;
000000000000100,34 -- as desired

SELECT TO_CHAR( 100.34,'fm099999999999999,00') FROM DUAL;
000000000000001,00 -- NOT What I want!! because ',' is for thousands
```

Is there a way to force the "comma" to be the "decimal separator" without altering the current session?

Comment: The problem in your third attempt is that Oracle does not view , in 2,000,000 as a THOUSANDS separator, it simply views it as "group" separator. In Indian ("lakh") notation, the same number is 20,00,000. Different cultures "group" digits differently (for integers!) so Oracle will do whatever you tell it. Similar to my answer, if you also need to group numbers (according to ANY mask), you would use G instead of explicit , or . - and then pass the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS specifically or use the session default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first format mask, with D representing the decimal delimiter, and then pass NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER as an explicit last parameter to TO_CHAR:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR( 100.34,'fm099999999999999D00') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(100.34,'FM0
-------------------
000000000000100.34

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.15
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR( 100.34,'fm099999999999999D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(100.34,'FM0
-------------------
000000000000100,34
```